# radnumerictextbox decimal saving 4.1 but not 4.0

Tags: asp.net, textbox, telerik, decimal

I am writing code that uses a radnumerictextbox from telerik.  Users are able to enter a decimal value and save it such as 4.1 but when they type 4.0 or 3.0 in the text box it corrects it to "4" or "3" and then that is what is saved into the database.  I have tried some of the numberformat options like KeepTrailingZerosOnFocus but all that does is put the zeros when you click into the text box and then they disappear onblur.  How can I get the RadNumericTextBox to behave like I want it?  My Code is below:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="radTxtScore" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Enter Score" AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="18" Width="98%">
     <NumberFormat AllowRounding="False"/>
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Comment: I basically want what is 'literally' typed in the textbox to be saved.  I dont really want to have to use a asp textbox and put number validation on it, although it may warrant it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired functionality you ned to format the number to allow the 0 decimal. I have tested this and is working as per your requirements.

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="radTxtScore" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Enter Score" AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="18" Width="98%" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="1">

</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

I have added the NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="1"

Comment: I must have the rounding set to False because of being a score.  If you take out the <NumberFormat AllowRounding="False"> you do get 4.0 displayed, but the value saved is only 4.  I am using some server code logic to ensure I save a .0 after a number when I want it.  However it will not display correctly.    You solution will not work for me because there may be the need to store more precision that one decimal place.  I only want what the user types in to be literally stored in the database   = if they type 4.0 store 4.0 if they type 55.23445 store that. No rounding can be allowed.

Comment: @GTBeekeeper thats not what you asked in your question.